# Domain not pointing to server, redirecting from .in to .com

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, vps, forwarding, dns-zone

I ran into a weird situation. I have these two domains example.com and example.in. Earlier I had example.in forwarded to example.com. Now I want example.in to point to my VPS server. I changed the Hostnames and Nameservers, changed A Record but the example.in is still redirecting to example.com. I have no idea what is going on. I contacted my Domain Registrar and Hosting provider. None of the two have any clue why this is happening. I checked the .in via traceroute and it is showing the IP of VPS server, but when I access the domain in a browser it ends up opening .com website.

I have no clue what is going on. Everything is configured correctly. No issues in the nameservers, no redirects exist on Domain Control Panel. I checked in cPanel for Redirects there are none. My website on VPS is totally inaccessible now.

Domain is bigsnip DOT in redirecting to bigsnip DOT com.

Comment: DNS records are cached and DNS changes take time to propagate. Also your web browser may have cached the original HTTP 301 redirect: see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16154672/2952385)

Comment: It has been more than 48 hours, which is more than usual time for DNS to propagate. Flushed the dnscache. Also checked via page testing tools like pingdom and gtmetrix. Redirect is still there.

Comment: The [video tutorial](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/cpanel/cpanel-manage-domains/setting-up-redirect-cpanel) how to redirect traffic from one domain to another domain via cPanel [web hosting control panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_control_panel). This can be done at the domain level or for specific web pages. For example, domain.com and it's web traffic can be redirected to anotherdomain.com OR domain.com/aboutus.html can be redirected to anotherdomain.com/about.html

Answer (score 3):

Your webserver is doing the redirect:

```
Kadath:~$ curl -i http://bigsnip.in/
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Tue, 19 Apr 2016 11:25:14 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.31
Location: http://bigsnip.com/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Kadath:~$ host bigsnip.in
bigsnip.in has address 45.40.138.76
bigsnip.in mail is handled by 0 bigsnip.in.
```

Provided that `45.40.138.76` is the IP address for your VPS, you do not have a DNS problem, you have a web server configuration problem. In any case, there is nothing detectably wrong with the DNS setup for `bigsnip.in`.

Comment: Yes, that is the IP for my server. This is the reason, everything seems to be working fine. Don't know from where the redirect is happening. I created a new account (for a new website) in my VPS server with name .com. Since I wanted to point .in to the website so I changed the account name to .in. Could this be the reason?

Comment: Have you checked recently? At my end bigsnip.in is no longer redirecting to bigsnip.com.

Comment: Yes, it is now redirecting fine. Domain took a lot time than usual to propagate. Everything is fine now.